# How to call a function in dijit progress bar's progress change event

Tags: dojo

I am doing a drag and drop file uploader using dojo1.3 toolkit, I can't upgrade this to Dojo's latest version because all other works are done with dojo1.3.

My problem is, I want to call a function on every change of a child progress bar's progress for updating the parent progress bar's progress.

I seen in dojo1.8 `dijit.watch()`, this function not available in dojo1.3.

Is there any other method in dojo1.3, I'm totally stuck.

Comment: Isn't `dijit.watch` for debugging purposes?

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is you could just import some files from Dojo 1.8, which provide the required function.
 
This way you won't have to migrate completely to Dojo 1.8.

But this needs to be done carefully, so that it doesn't affect your previous code.

I have tried this for Dojo TimeStamp dijit and it worked pretty fine for me.

Comment: thank u for ur answer,
 I import dojo.Stateful for calling watch function, did not work,
Can u please tell which files are import.

Answer (score 0):

In 1.4 and above (don't know about 1.3) the fileUploader has an `onProgress` event, which you can override.